# Error inserting string key,value in unordered_map

Tags: c++

I am writing my first STL program in C++, and I am facing this issue.

This is my program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    // n : number of file extenstions
    // m : number of filenames to identify
    string extension, type, filename;
    cin >> n >> m;

    unordered_map<string,string> hashmap;

    while(n--)
    {
        cin >> extension >> type;
        hashmap.insert(make_pair<string,string>(extension,type));
    }
    while(m--)
    {
        cin >> filename;
        extension = filename.substr(filename.find_last_of('.')+1);
        cout << extension << endl;
    }
}
```

My input file is :

```
5 6
html text/html
htm text/html
png image/png
svg image/svg+xml
txt text/plain
index.html
this.file.has.lots.of.dots.txt
nodotsatall
virus.exe
dont.let.the.png.fool.you
case.matters.TXT
```

I am getting error : `no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(std::string&, std::string&)’` . I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Is your input relevant? If not, remove it. Ditto for the loops, extension finding, lookup, output.

Comment: You really should include the `string` header.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the line

```
make_pair<string,string>(extension,type)
```

It should instead be

```
make_pair(extension, type)
```

Comment: Or at least `make_pair<string&,string&>(extension,type)`, but I like the auto deduction...

Comment: @skypjack : I was referencing from here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/ . There also they have done the same way, <string,double> and not <string&,double>, but still that works.  Please help me clear the doubt.

Comment: First of all, I'd rather use `make_pair(extension, type)` and let the compiler to deduce the types in any case, to avoid any risks. That said, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair. Indeed, as far as I understand (I'm far from being an expert) the deduced types in your case would be `T&, U&`, thus using the couple `T, U` (as `<string, string>`) ends in a function prototype that doesn't accept references as arguments, while your are explicitly using references to initialize the *pair* (that's why you got the error). I simply suggested to specify the right type for them. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd rather use `make_pair(extension, type)` and let the compiler to deduce the types in any case, to avoid any risks, as someone else suggested.

Anyway, I see that the details below are interesting from your point of view, thus it's worth to put them in a dedicated response, hoping they are also right.

That said, see the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair).

As far as I understand (I'm far from being an expert) the deduced types in your case would be T&, U&, thus using the couple `T, U` (as `<string, string>`) ends in a function prototype that doesn't accept references as arguments (that's why you got the error and that one specifically).

You can use instead the following pattern in your case:

```
make_pair<string&,string&>(extension,type)
```

This one works for you actually use references to initialize the pair and you are going to require the sames as template arguments.

Again, for the `make_pair` can easily deduce the types of its arguments, you can freely omit them and I strongly suggest to do that.